# appcompat primarycolour implementing

Tags: java, android

My styles.xml file is refusing to work. What am i doing wrong? It says expected closing tag and needs attribute value...

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@colors/Primary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@colors/PrimaryDark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated, which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name=”colorAccent”>@colors/Accent</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml (stored in res\values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="Primary">#03A9F4</color>
   <color name="PrimaryDark">#0288D1</color>
   <color name="Accent">#1DE9B6</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to say @color instead of @colors. Colors is the name of your colors.xml file, however you are seeking the color resources, which you access using @color

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/Primary</item>
```

Comment: i've made those changes but it didn't fix the problem